# SDKTools and AFNetworking dependency

Tags: skmaps

We are using the skobbler iOS sdk and SDKTools to download maps for offline use. The SDKTools package, however has a version of AFNetworking bundled with it which conflicts with our version of afnetworking that we use from cocoapods. Is there an easy way to handle these dependency issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the AFNetworking dependency is tied into our SDKTools cocoapod. The workaround would be to use the SDKTools from the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) - there you have access to the source code & project and can remove the AFNetworking reference.

In the future will change the SDKTools cocoapod to not include the AFNetworking library but reference it as a dependent cocoapod.